# Azure AD B2C invite as guest for administration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Recently I am starting to get an error when trying to invite a guest user to my Azure AD B2C tenant, for only user from a specific domain. The reason i'm inviting is to share the administration process with the specified user.

The error i'm getting is: *User account is disabled*

So far what I've tried:

1. Using the *Users* > *New guest user*" UI in Azure AD blade.
2. Using the "*Organizational relationships* > *New guest user*" UI in Azure AD blade.
3. Using the *Users* > *New guest user*" UI in Azure AD B2C blade.
4. Using graph api *invitations* endpoints.

Observation: Only happen for user from specific domain (External Azure D) but works for those with Microsoft account.

Comment: Did the external user accept the invitation?

Comment: @MartinBrandl the invitation can't even reach the user. The error i'm getting is as stated above.

Comment: may be you can try raising a support ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone's benefit here I'm posting the answer after consulting with Microsoft support.

There are 2 possible issues that might cause you unable to invite the Guest user to the Azure AD:

1. Users are not properly deleted. When you search for the user email, it might not be visible in the UI, but still unable to invite. It's partly because the UI has some limited search capabilities (exact/startswith email or name only).

**Solution**: You can use graph api to query for the user. You should definitely try to look for the user based on the `OtherMails` field.

2. User you're trying to invite is from an Azure AD tenant that is also one of identity provider trusted in your Azure AD B2C. This is the cause of the issue with my implementation that I found.
   When the user use their Azure AD credential logging in for the 1st time to my application (Azure AD B2C), a "social account" is created automatically in the Azure AD B2C. This account is created with the `UserPrincipalName` in the format of `cpim_guid@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`, and `AccountEnabled` false (disabled). Their Azure AD email will be in the `OtherMails` property. This is why you can't find the user by their email in the UI, and you have to know the exact name they use in their Azure AD in order to find them.

**Solution**: If you can find in the UI, typically their `MemberType` is Member `Source` is `External Azure AD`, you can just delete the user. If not, use graph api to query for their email in `OtherMails` property. Then immediately invite the user as guest. They should have no problem logging in to the B2C application again as the `social account` will be created automatically.

**Note**: Ensure that you don't use Azure AD B2C policies that adds additional attributes to the user logging in using social account. If yes, you'd need some other strategy for deleting the user, inviting as guest, recreating the social account, and restoring back the additional attributes.